# Strange Error when downloading files with download.file

Tags: r, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to download historical WACC data from a website. I know that I have the URLs correct because I do actually download the files, except instead of showing up as .xls fiels they show up as 'documents' on my mac.

Here is my code

```
WACC = c("wacc98", "wacc99", "wacc00", "wacc01", "wacc02", "wacc03","wacc04",
        "wacc05", "wacc06", "wacc07", "wacc08", "wacc09","wacc10",
        "wacc11", "wacc12", "wacc13", "wacc14", "wacc15","wacc16",
        "wacc17", "wacc18", "wacc19", "wacc20", "wacc21")

WACC.urls = c()

for (j in WACC){
  WACC.urls[j] = paste("https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/pc/archives/",j,
                       '.xls', sep = '')
  download.file(WACC.urls[j], 
                paste("~/Business Cycle/WACC/",j,sep=''))
}
```

This code downloads the files, but has them listed as 'documents' and not excel files. So what I see is the attached image.[Image of file when opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdkvy.png)

Even more interesting is that there are no error or warning messages

Comment: Your computer will use the file extension to determine what the file contains. When you are using `download.file`, you are specifying the "destfile" parameter bit you are not including the `.xls` in the name. Be sure to add it to the path `paste("~/Business Cycle/WACC/",j,".xls",sep='')`